# Unable to retrieve column value as displayed in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, tiny-tds

The column(of type image) value(binary- hexa) will look like in SSMS,

```
0x89500000D0A1A0A0000000D494844520000000...
```

And while trying to get this value through code(tinytds- ruby), i'm getting the output in non utf format like below,

```
BM6K□□□□□�□□□□□□□□□��(K�������...
```

Also the sql connection is established with utf-8 encoding.

So is there any way to retrieve the value in binary format?

Comment: The data type is byte-array, the client is trying to display the array as text, once you receive the results from database use some format function to convert byte-array to hex

Comment: thanks!! ruby: value.unpack('H*') worked!!